# Как узнать, что сработал JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Всем доброго дня! В процессе написания кода для скрапинга, решил поработать над его быстродействием. Обычно я писал что то вроде `time.sleep(5)` что бы уж точно убедиться что даже при медленном интернете JS успел про грузиться. Так вот, есть ли способы как то узнать это? Думал делать что то вроде

```
wait_element = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH, Xpath)))
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(Xpath)
...other instructions...
```

Но что, если при выполнении JS не добавляется никаких видимых изменений, а рыться во всем html коде сайта (тот что через F12, простите мой словарный запас, если напутал), особенно если он достаточно сложный... Да и как можно понять, на html коде что JS сработал, мне не понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот так например.

```
console.log(element)
```